# How can shears/reflections/enlargements be represented by 4x4 matrices?

Tags: 3d, matrix, transformation, scale

I understand that 4x4 matrices can represent transformations on a 3d point (represented as x, y, z, w)

Eg, a translation is

```
[1 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0]
[0 0 1 0]
[x y z 1]
```

where x, y and z are the amount to move the point along each axis.

I know how to represent translations, scaling and rotations but how are other transformations such as shears (with any invariant plane and shear factor), reflections (in any plane) and enlargements (with any center and any scale factor) represented?

The end goal is to have c++ functions to create a translation matrix.
Eg:

```
Matrix4x4.generateReflection(Vector3d planeNormal);
Matrix4x4.generateEnlargment(float centerX, float centerY,
                             float centerZ, float scaleFactor);
```

These would return an instance of a `Matrix4x4` class with the elements set such that multiplying it by a point returns the sheared/reflected/enlarged point.

Comment: Enlargement as you call it is actually scaling. Here's a good article about matrix transformations:[link](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/transform/index.htm).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pure math with no game-specific pieces, maybe try http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch I disagree. "Would a professional game developer give me a better/different/more specific answer to this question than other programmers?" Even if we change programmers to something more general I doubt many mathematicians have a more practical understanding of matrices designed to transform 3d coordinates spaces than a game developer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=rotation  <-- this is a math topic, not a games topic, and there's not even anything about real-time 3D rendering involved.  this is an introductory linear algebra topic in every single university math program I've ever heard of.  not only is it better suited to math.se.com, they have MathJax support (GDSE opted out of it partially since this isn't a math-oriented site) and that will make answering meaningfully way easier.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for guidance on the construction of matrices for specific more complex transformations. The standard recipe for this is the following:

- Determine the translation to the new origin, and build the homogenous matrix for this translation.
- Determine where each basis vector (unit vector along each axis, relative to the new origin) will be mapped to relative to the new origin. These resultant vectors will be the columns of the resultant non-translational homogenous matrix component.
- Multiply the translational and non-translational matrices to obtain the net transformation matrix. Be careful to do this in the correct order, depending on whether your vectors are row vectors pre-applied to matrices, or column-vectors post-applied to the matrix.